Why are the homeomorphisms from the unit circle to the unit circle preserving measure affine?
Why are the homeomorphisms from the unit circle to the unit circle preserving measure affine? The affine is composition of rotation and continue automorphism.

Take any homeomorphism $h$ of the unit circle (say $C$).
Composing $h$ with an appropriate rotation, we see that, without loss of generality, $1=1+0i$ is a fixed point of $h$.
Considering parametrizations $[0,2\pi)\ni t\mapsto e^{it}$ and $(0,2\pi]\ni t\mapsto e^{it}$ of $C$, we see that $h$ is given by a map of one of the following two types:

$[0,2\pi)\ni t\mapsto f(t)\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $f$ is a homeomorphism, $f(0)=0$, and $f(2\pi-)=2\pi$;

$(0,2\pi]\ni t\mapsto f(t)\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $f$ is a homeomorphism, $f(0+)=2\pi$, and $f(2\pi)=0$.


Consider now type 1. Then, by the intermediate value theorem, the function $f$ is strictly increasing. So, for each $x\in[0,2\pi)$, $f$ maps the interval $[0,x]$ onto the interval $[0,f(x)]$. Since $h$ is measure preserving, we have $f(x)=x$, for each $x\in[0,2\pi)$. So, the homeomorphism $h$ is the identity map and hence a rotation.
Type 2 is considered similarly. Alternatively, it can be reduced to type 1 by composing $h$ with the reflection $e^{it}\mapsto e^{-it}=e^{i(2\pi-t)}$ for $t\in[0,2\pi)$.
Thus, $h$ is necessarily a rotation or the composition of a rotation with the reflection. $\quad\Box$
